# How to prevent OpenSSH from creating a new known_hosts file every time it updates it?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

It seems that every time I accept a new host key, ssh (I've tested 8.6p1 and 9.3p2) does the following steps:

- Move the `known_hosts` file to `known_hosts.old`;
- Create a new `known_hosts` file;
- Copy the contents of `known_hosts.old` to `known_hosts`;
- Add the new entry to the new `known_hosts`.

All well and good, except that, like many people, I've put my dotfiles under version control. The `known_hosts` file is a link to a file in my git repository. After all, if I've accepted a host key on my desktop, then I don't want to risk a MITM if I connect to the same host from my laptop. That's the whole point of the known_hosts file, after all.

The above procedure followed by ssh doesn't play nice: after I accept a new host, it's `known_hosts.old` which is a link to my version-controlled file, which never gets updated.

How do I tell `ssh` to please stop creating `known_hosts.old` and just edit `known_hosts` directly? I have no need for such a coarse backup method anyway - the file is already under version control. I've perused TFM but I didn't find any such option.

Comment: May be it would be simpler to add `.ssh` under version control?

Comment: @AlexeyTen It already is, that's the whole point of the question.

Comment: I believe Alexey meant not "all files symlinked to some other directory which is under version control" or even ".ssh is a symlink to some directory under version control", but "`~/.ssh` is a normal directory with standard structure composed of normal files which is itself under version control on its own". In this case, no files in it need to be symlinked to be under version control (exactly opposite is true, better not symlink anything into outside to have it version-controlled), and no problem like described will happen. At least, not with Git.

Comment: Upd: I think the O.P. better needs something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398648/git-inverse-ignoring-gitignore)

Comment: Actually, I've meant to symlink `~/.ssh` to directory under version control. I have this configuration for years and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it is hardcoded in a source code, so one option is to rewrite it to suit your needs (not recommended).

Comment: Thanks. That's an unfortunate decision by openssh devs.